# How do I tweak an existing library to follow Yii standards when created an extension out of it?

Tags: yii

I want to take the HybridAuth library on sourceforge.net and turn it into a Yii extension. However, the library does not follow Yii standards. For example, a class named Hybrid_Auth is located in a file named Auth.php.

I really don't want to modify the source - that way the code can be easily updated later with new releases of HybridAuth. If I try to instantiate a Hybrid_Auth object in Yii, it will look for a file called HyBrid_Auth.php, which doesn't exist. How could I get Yii to look in the Auth.php file for the Hybrid_Auth class? Thanks.

Comment: Someone wrote one. It works, but it's not that great. A good start tho... [http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/hybridauth/](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/hybridauth/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about put it into extension folder and create your own Factory class that will create instance of needed class?

so it will look like

```
extensions/library_folder/
extensions/YourClass.php
```

and something like this in class

```
require_once 'library_folder/Hybrid_Auth.php';

class YourClass {
    public function __construct(){
        return new HybridAuth();     
    }
}
```